# How do I add /blog/ as a prefix to permalink structure for blog posts, tag pages, etc.?

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm using WordPress 3.1.3 as a full CMS, installed in the root directory of a domain. I have it setup using the built in options to have a static page as the home page, and then my blog at `http://www.example.com/blog`.

What I would like is to have my single blog posts, category pages, archive pages, and tag pages, and any other blog-related pages have the "prefix" of `/blog/` in their link structure. So a post URL would be `www.example.com/blog/post-title`

---

Right now, I only have the category pages working correctly. This was accomplished by adding the following line to my `.htacces` file:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then, I set the Category Base to "blog" on the Permalinks Settings page in WordPress. This gives category pages the URL of: `www.example.com/blog/category-name` (without removing the category prefix in `.htaccess`, they had the URL `category/blog/category-name`).

---

In an attempt to get this working for the other things I want it to work for, I set my Tag Base to "blog."  I also made my Custom Permalink Structure: `/blog/%postname%` (as suggested by a few threads I've found searching on Google).

These settings give the URLs for the single blog posts, tags pages, and archive pages the URL structure I'm looking for. However, it makes them all lead to 404 errors.

I deleted my `.htaccess` file to ensure WordPress was writing to it, and it is. If I remove the `/blog/` from the permalink structure, everything works correctly, but I no longer have the URL structure I'm looking for.

I'm at a loss as to what I should do. I keep reading threads and guides saying this is as simple as adding `/blog/` to the permalink structure, but so far it hasn't been nearly that simple.

`.htaccess` contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As a side note, the permalink shown while editing a post is "wrong". It won't show the final link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Settings>Permalinks and add it to the permalink structures

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried, and was resulting in 404 errors.  So I had it disabled for a few hours, and decided to try it again after reading your response.  It's now working for my single post pages.  I also got the category pages working again.  That just leaves the tag pages and the archive pages that need the /blog/ in them.

Comment: If you look at the page there is a spot for the tags as well. As for the archive pages are you talking about the the page that shows the list of articles, tags, categories, etc. or archived posts

Comment: With the tags, if I add blog into the Tag Base area it gives me the correct URL structure "mydomain.com/blog/tag-name" but that page then gives me a 404 error.  With the archives, I mean the page that shows the archived posts for a particular month.  I would like the URL to be mydomain.com/blog/2011/05.  That URL structure shows up when I click an archive link, but also gives a 404 error.  And now I'm getting 404 errors for the single blog posts again.  Could this be a plugin that's causing problems?

Comment: Is your .htaccess setup right?

Comment: I believe so, Wordpress adds in the rewrite rules any time I change them.  Should there be anything in particular in there for something like this?

Comment: first check to make sure your .htaccess exists if not you need to get the contents of it and make it yourself.

Comment: It does exist, and I removed the other things I had added so all that's in there is that's below (with the correct line breaks), and I'm still getting the 404 errors on everything but the category pages.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

I appreciate you taking the time to help, too.

Comment: Next time just post the code in your question above. with code tags. Ill edit your post with it but it will not be visible till a mod views it over. Try taking out the RewriteBase / sometimes the server does not need this or will spit an error.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that.

I removed the line, but am still receiving 404 errors as before.

Comment: do you have a link that i can try? if not its cool. Just want to see if it is just your its affecting or if it affects everyone. Also have you read the codex page on this http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks especially towards the end.

Comment: Sure, I've been working on the blog area here [link](http://www.dvorakdesigns.com/blog). Then a post here [link](http://www.dvorakdesigns.com/blog/test-post). I'll take a look at the permalinks page again.

Comment: this is something i got from a fellow member @toscho he said try to add this line ^blog/category/(.+)$ instead of your previous

Comment: scratch the last comment. Unless its better working for you. Unfortunately i am a little stumped on this. Have you made sure that your server works with this.

Comment: I think I got most everything working.  I removed "blog" from the Category Base, and for whatever reason everything but the category pages is working now.  I now have this line in my .htaccess `RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.+)$ http://www.dvorakdesigns.com/$1 [R=301,L]` but the category pages are showing up as dvorakdesigns.com/category/category-name.  Was that the correct implementation for what toscho gave you?

Comment: And you want /blog/category/category-name or /blog/category-name

Comment: If blog/category/category-name is possible, that would be ideal.  Otherwise, blog/category-name is fine.

Comment: Ill have to think on this. In the mean time try googling around on this subject

Comment: I think figured it out.  It was as simple as adding blog/category as the Category Base, and then blog/tag as the Tag Base.  With this in the .htaccess file: `RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.dvorakdesigns.com/$1 [R=301,L]` (this keeps the url from being category/blog/category).  Lets hope everything stays working!  Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Sound good. No Problem

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I have a taxonomy that moves from `/mytaxonomy` to `/blog/mytaxonomy` when I do this, which is not what I want. I need `/blog` for posts and `/mytaxonomy` for taxonomy items.

Comment: This is FALSE, it will attach the prefix to ALL your custom post types

Answer (score 33):

You get 404 errors when you add `/blog/` to the custom permalink structure and then also add `/blog/` to the category base. It should only be added to one, the custom permalink structure.

If you leave your category base and tag base blank and just add `/blog/` to the front of the custom permalink structure to make it look like this `/blog/%postname%` - this will get the desired result.

Your pages will look like this: `domain.example/pagename/`
Your post URL will look like this: `domain.example/blog/postname`
Your category URL will look like this - `domain.example/blog/category/postname`

Comment: Good catch on adding to only one section. This solution also will add /blog/ to the category and archive pages which is good. This should really be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm glad this method also applies to URL for the categories page.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: it will attach the prefix to ALL your custom post types

Comment: A usual question here would probably be: How do you manage this for just "post" post types and how do you translate /blog for example for different languages? :)