# /blog/ permalink prefix causes category pages to 404

Tags: categories, permalinks

I've followed the instructions in this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21208/51164 - And it worked but now category pages (/blog/news) don't show up, they 404 instead. Although on that post it mentions they should work. My permalink is set to custom and `/blog/%postname%/`

I've tried re-saving permalinks and flushing the rewrites but it hasn't helped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you have a page named "Blog" with a slug "blog" in your system too? You can't have that with the permalink structure you have created because the permalink for this page would also be /blog/ and therefore cause a conflict. Try changing the slug of the page "blog" to something else.

Comment: I did have that, and that was assigned to the blog index page. I tried changing it but that didn't fix it unfortunately. It also caused my actual blog index to not be located at /blog, but (as I changed it to) /blog-posts

Comment: Have you already done the basic debug steps (deactivating all plugins, changing theme to default, etc.)? I tried to reproduce your problem with setup I think you have (custom structure /blog/%postname%/ - category base left empty - page named blog as the posts page) and permalink structure works just fine for categories, posts and all.

Comment: Oh wait. One fast question. You DO have posts in that category (news)? Archive pages for categories and tags only exist if there are posts tagged into that taxonomy. Just checking before going deeper.

Comment: Yep, nothing seems to be interfering with it, and there are posts within the /news category. It works just fine when the posts(the category) are loaded via ajax, but if you just go to /blog/news, it 404's. However if it's working for you then I'm really not sure what I've done wrong... :/

Comment: Again: have you tried disabling all plugins and switched to default wp theme?